# Change language of WinRT MapControl

Tags: windows-runtime, maps

I am using [WinRT MapsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.aspx) in my universal application, which belongs to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps'. I want to change language of maps when my application language is changed.

I see a Language property in there (Inherited from FrameworkElement), I tried setting it as

```
Language = "ar-SA"
```

in XAML and also through code, but it did not work. I tried searching about it in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn615001.aspx) documentation as well, but couldn't help myself.

Comment: The Bing Maps control used a `culture` property, but the `MapsControl` doesn't apparently have the same functionality.

Comment: yes.. looks like it doesn't have it :/